# For JS strings, is s === "" always the same as s.length == 0?

Tags: javascript, string, equation

For JS strings, is `s === ""` always the same as `s.length == 0`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is except in an edge case where `s` is a string *object* instead of a string *primitive*:

```js
const s = new String("");
console.log(s.length === 0); // true
console.log(s === "");       // false
```

`s === ""` doesn't work because `===` doesn't do any type conversion, so an object is never `===` to a primitive.

JavaScript is slightly unusual in that it has object equivalents to its primitive types. You're almost always dealing with string primitives rather than string objects, but string objects *do* exist and this distinction can be valid. It's much less an important thing to know now than it used to be. Back before ES5's strict mode, if you extended the `String.prototype` with an `isEmpty` method (for instance), your `length === 0` check would work but the `=== ""` would not:

```js
// Very old loose-mode pre-ES5 code
String.prototype.wrongIsEmpty = function() {
    return this === ""; // WRONG
};
String.prototype.rightIsEmpty = function() {
    return this.length === 0; // Right
};

console.log("".wrongIsEmpty()); // false
console.log("".rightIsEmpty()); // true
```

The reason for the problem is that prior to ES5's strict mode, `this` in a function was always an object, not a primitive, so those methods see a string *object* as `this`.

In code written for ES5 and later, you'd write that in strict mode and it wouldn't matter which check you used, because in strict mode, `this` doesn't have to be an object and so the `this` the methods see is the primitive string:

```js
"use strict";

Object.defineProperty(String.prototype, "isEmpty1", {
    value: function() {
        return this === ""; // This is fine
    },
    writable: true,
    configurable: true
});
Object.defineProperty(String.prototype, "isEmpty2", {
    value: function() {
        return this.length === 0; // This is fine
    },
    writable: true,
    configurable: true
});

console.log("".isEmpty1()); // true
console.log("".isEmpty2()); // true
```

(That also uses `defineProperty`, but it's strict mode that matters for the value of `this`.)

---

It's very rare to create string objects, and almost never the correct thing to do.

Comment: your `s` is not a string (value), but an instance of `String`. what is the deeper sense?

Comment: @NinaScholz - I'm sorry, I don't understand your question...? Both a string primitive and a string object are "strings," but I think I'm just missing what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

**NO**

try for

```js
s1 = new String('');
s2 = []
s3 = {length: 0}
```

Comment: I already covered that first one. The second two aren't relevant: The OP said *strings*, not arrays or other objects.